# MySQL order by column with letters and numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this column in my table with shelf names

```
M2-8-3
N1-12-1 
N1-3-8 
N2-6-1 
O1-11-3
O2-1-5 
O2-10-1 
O2-10-2 
O2-10-6 
O2-16-7 
O2-17-6 
O2-17-7 
O2-4-2
```

When i order by it ascending it gives the result visible above but how could i write the query to get the result visible below

```
M2-8-3
N1-3-8 
N1-12-1 
N2-6-1 
O1-11-3
O2-1-5 
O2-4-2
O2-10-1 
O2-10-2 
O2-10-6 
O2-16-7 
O2-17-6 
O2-17-7
```

The difference is in the position of `N1-3-8` and `O2-4-2`

Comment: Let me clarify. Imagine 3 components to the string, 1=CHAR, 2= INT, 3=INT. Order by 1, then 2, then 3, yes?

Comment: just split it to 3 parts, convert the 2nd and 3rd ones to numbers and order by part1,part2,part3 or use string functions to format the numbers with leading zeroes and order by the formatted expression

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT col
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-', 1),
         SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-', -2),
                   1,
                   INSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-', -2), '-') - 1),
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-', -1)
```

This is the brute force approach, where each of the three terms in the `ORDER BY` clause corresponds to a portion of your hyphenated string.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a slightly simpler method:

```
order by substring_index(col, '-', 1),
         substring_index(col, '-', -2) + 0,
         col
```

This ends up converting the middle portion to a number for sorting purposes.